# How do you get a channel object from a channel ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically what it says in the title. I want to get a channel object, and I have the channel ID, in both the form of just the number and with the <# and >. How can i get the channel object from either of those with discord.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the channel id which can be used in an on_message or a task loop or command the same message was sent from by storing it in the this_channel variable, then with the command, it can retrieve that variable and message whatever you want to the channel from there.

```
    this_channel = ctx.channel.id

     
    channel = client.get_channel(int(this_channel))
    await channel.send('Heres the message')
```

Comment: Thanks, the channel = client.get_channel was exactly what I needed. I had actually already figured it out, but i needed the part where its converted back into an integer lol. Forgot to do that. Either way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't include much else in how you are using the channel object, if you want to mention or get its name or id:

```
@client.command()
async def channel(ctx):
    channel_name = ctx.channel.mention
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    
    await ctx.send("""
    Channel name: {channel_name}
    Channel ID: {channel_id}
    """)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have the ID, and I want to get the object from that ID so that i can send the message in that specific channel. For example I’d get the ID of 12345 (making this up of course) and then I want to get the channel object so I can do await channel.send(message), with channel being the channel object created earlier.